# Setting Cookies via AJAX CORS Response and accessing them in document.cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I have a working CORS set up in my app.
On the server side REST service I added setting of cookies in the ajax responses.This works great ,the next Ajax requests to the CORS service are sent with cookies.

Now I want on the client side to get/set the values these set cookies from javascript.
**document.cookies** returns an empty string **even though they are sent from the browser with each request to the rest service**(this means they are stored somewhere).

I am running both the service and the client from localhost, and in chrome developer tools in the resources tab under the cookies section these sent cookies are not present.

Where are these cookies stored and how can I access them ?

Comment: Javascript cannot read cookies sent to a different domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only interface JavaScript (on a webpage) has for reading cookies is `document.cookie` which contains the cookies for the current HTML document.

Cookies set via a cross-domain Ajax request are not for the current HTML document, so are not available through that interface.

XMLHttpRequest does have a `getAllResponseHeaders()` method, but `Set-Cookie` headers are suppressed by browsers so you can't access them as they are being set either.

Comment: I am still intrigued about these XHR cookies  storage ,policy and if there is a way to access them .Do you happen to know some reference about these special cookies?

Comment: There's nothing special about them. They are just cookies from a different domain from that of the page itself.