# not able to set the cookie from script tag javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, setcookie, httpcookie

On the Html Side

```
<script src="http://localhost:3002/widget-load?clientId=1" type="text/javascript">
```

And on the `nodejs`

```
app.get('/widget-load', function (req, res) {
   const { clientId } = req.query;

   // Try 1
   res.cookie("clientId", clientId, {
        // httpOnly: true
   });

   // Try 2
   res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `clientId=${clientId};`);
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/static/js/widget-load.js');

});
```

but this is not working. Even I tried

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

even i am using `cookie-parser`

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

but still this is not working. No cookie is getting set on browser

Comment: did you try with cookieParser? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209531/9175097

Comment: @MWO, yes i am using cookie parser

Answer (score 1):

With a combination from the answer in my link, and your requierments, it is working here, cookie is set to `clientId=1`. For cross site resources you have to set the options to `sameSite: 'none'` and `secure: 'false'` if you are not running `ssl`.

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/widget-load', function (req, res) {
    const { clientId } = req.query;
    var cookie = req.cookies.clientId;
    if (cookie === undefined) {
      res.cookie('clientId',clientId, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: 'false' });
      console.log('cookie created successfully');
    } else {
      // yes, cookie was already present 
      console.log('cookie exists', cookie);
    } 


    // // Try 1
    // res.cookie("clientId", clientId, {
    //      // httpOnly: true
    // });
 
    // // Try 2
    // res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `clientId=${clientId};`);
     res.sendFile('widget-load.js',{'root':'public'});
 
 });

 app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000`)
  })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i want to read that cookie inside the browser

Comment: i tried the same as try 1 but not able to read the cookie on browser side

Comment: i can read it. in network pane of dev tools

Comment: yes i can see in the network tab, can i read it in a variable? document.cookie is empty

Comment: as you can see in the update, you can see it in the chrome cookies storage.

Comment: but still i can not read the cookies using document.cookie, and now if browser make any other call , then on nodejs side i am not able to get cookies by req.headers.cookie

Comment: i think its because its a cors request, it does not save it in document.cookies https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769954/9175097